# window without wndproc

Tags: c++, windows

I am curious it is possible to create a window without using WndProc.

So I would like to register the window-class with the lpfnWndProc field set to NULL;
And using the msg ( that is given by TranslateMessage(&msg) ) in my own way.

Is there any disadvantages of this?

Thanks ahead, and sorry for my grammar.

Edit #1:
Okay, I have a window, but I am wrong somewhere.

```
 MSG msg;
    while(PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,NULL,NULL,PM_REMOVE)) {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) return false;
        else {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                switch (msg.message) {
                case WM_CREATE:
                    createContext();
                    break;
                default:
                    DispatchMessage(&msg);
                    break;
                }
        }
    } 
    return true;
```

The createContext is not getting called.
Why? Where I am wrong?
Yeah, maybe the WM_CREATE message is to be sent to WndProc (DefWindowProc now), but are there any way to get it outside from the WndProc?

Comment: That is a very unusual kind of thing to do with a window. Why do you want to do that? There's probably a different approach that's more suitable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't set it to `NULL`.  However, you'll notice that [`DefWindowProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633572(v=vs.85).aspx)'s signature matches the [`WindowProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx) callback's signature.  Simply give it `DefWindowProc` if you'd like a reasonable default.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry that makes no sense. Without the wndproc how can you even get hold of the message?

A window without a window proc is not a window!

Answer (score 3):

No, you'll break SendMessage().  Only PostMessage() can work.  Supporting SendMessage is required.